# How to cast string to timestamp with nanoseconds in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I am working with data with timestamps that contain nanoseconds and am trying to convert the string to timestamp format.

Here is what the 'Time' column looks like:

```python
+---------------+
|      Time     |
+---------------+
|091940731349000|
|092955002327000|
|092955004088000|
+---------------+
```

I would like to cast it to:

```python
+------------------+
|    Timestamp     |
+------------------+
|09:19:40.731349000| 
|09:29:55.002327000| 
|09:29:55.004088000|  
+------------------+
```

From what I have found online, I don't need to use a udf to do this and there should be a native function that I can use.

I have tried `cast` and `to_timestamp` but got 'null' values:

```python
df_new = df.withColumn('Timestamp', df.Time.cast("timestamp"))
df_new.select('Timestamp').show()

+---------+    
|Timestamp|    
+---------+    
|     null|    
|     null|    
+---------+
```

Comment: Seems like you just want to do some string manipulation- that output is not a timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- Input is not a valid timestamp representation.
- Spark doesn't provide type that can represent time without date component

The closest you can get to the required output is to convert input to JDBC compliant `java.sql.Timestamp` format:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["091940731349000", "092955002327000", "092955004088000"], 
    "string"
).toDF("time")

df.select(regexp_replace(
  col("time"),
  "^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{9}).*", 
  "1970-01-01 $1:$2:$3.$4"
).cast("timestamp").alias("time")).show(truncate = False)

# +--------------------------+
# |time                      |
# +--------------------------+
# |1970-01-01 09:19:40.731349|
# |1970-01-01 09:29:55.002327|
# |1970-01-01 09:29:55.004088|
# +--------------------------+
```

If you want just a string skip cast and limit output to:

```py
df.select(regexp_replace(
  col("time"),
  "^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{9}).*", 
  "$1:$2:$3.$4"
).alias("time")).show(truncate = False)

# +------------------+
# |time              |
# +------------------+
# |09:19:40.731349000|
# |09:29:55.002327000|
# |09:29:55.004088000|
# +------------------+
```