# How to convert timestamp to bigint in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Am using python on spark environment and want to convert a dataframe coulmn from TIMESTAMP datatype to bigint (UNIX timestamp). The columns are as such: `("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS")`

```
timestamp_col               
2014-06-04 10:09:13.334422      
2015-06-03 10:09:13.443322      
2015-08-03 10:09:13.232431
```

I have read around and tried this among others:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

df1 = df.select((from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df.timestamp_col, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))).cast(TimestampType()).alias("unix_time_col"))
```

but the output gives rather NULL values.

```
+-------------+
|unix_time_col|
+-------------+
|         null|
|         null|
|         null|
```

Am using python3.7 on spark on hadoop environment with spark & hadoop versions: `spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7` on `google-colaboratory`
I must be missing out something. Please, any help?

Answer (score 3):

please remove ".SSSSSS" in your code,  then it will work while converting to unixtimestamp i.e. instead of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS" write as below:

df1 = df.select(unix_timestamp(df.timestamp_col, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))

Comment: Thank you however, it was an `IOT` data project where `nano differences` in time was very significant, so in my case I really needed the `".SSSSSS"`

Comment: Hi,  please refer reply from below stackoverflow link , you will get solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435366/how-to-cast-string-to-timestamp-with-nanoseconds-in-pyspark

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import (DateType, StructType, StructField, StringType)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()

column_schema = StructType([StructField("timestamp_col", StringType())])
data = [['2014-06-04 10:09:13.334422'], ['2015-06-03 10:09:13.443322'], ['2015-08-03 10:09:13.232431']]

data_frame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=column_schema)

data_frame.withColumn("timestamp_col", data_frame['timestamp_col'].cast(DateType()))
data_frame = data_frame.withColumn('timestamp_col', unix_timestamp('timestamp_col'))
data_frame.show()
```

> **output**

```
+-------------+
|timestamp_col|
+-------------+
|   1401894553|
|   1433344153|
|   1438614553|
+-------------+
```